# Sass variables in Angular2 components

Tags: angular, sass

I use Angular2 and angular-cli in my project. I defined some Sass variables in the global style.scss file. How can I access these variables from my custom components (from component.scss)? Мaybe I have to import the separate file with these variables in each component.scss file.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should put your variables inside a seperate `.scss` file like `_vars.scss`. Notice the underscore in front of the name. This will tell the compiler that the  file should not be compiled. Which means you can only use it with `@import`.

Then for instance in your `component.scss` you can do (at the top of your file):

`@import "path/to/vars";`

No need to add the underscore nor the extension

Comment: I tried this but did not work for me. I am not able to have variables in my scss file. Please see my post here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401501/how-to-use-sass-in-angular2-application. Hope you may help.

Comment: Would this create duplicate code? Or is that what you mean by "tell the compiler that the output of the file should not be embedded." I'm not familiar with SASS inside of a component architecture so I'm not sure how Angular2 handles this.

Comment: variables, extendables, mixins and functions do not have an output when compiled. So no :). It's not about being angular2 or whatever framework, it's all plain scss